# how can i get all input fields values to an array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i get all input fields values to an array in jquery?

please see my codes bellow:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="a" />
<input type="text" name="b" value="hello" />
<input type="text" name="c" value="world" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_fields_values(){

        // too much code
        var arr=[];
        $.each($("input"),function(i,n){
            arr.push(n.value)
        }); 
        return arr;

        // is there any jquery method to get fields values to an array?
        // $('input').xxx() ?
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend using a `<form>` element with [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to accomplish your task,

```
var arr = $("input").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
```

Full code would be,

```
function get_fields_values(){
    return $("input").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6XXb/1/)

Comment: @anonymousUser: Thanks for your effort in making a demo for my post.!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.map` method.

```
function get_fields_values() {
  return $('input').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
｝
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_fields_values() {
  return $('input').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join("$");
｝
```